# Recode on multiple conditions dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I want to recode a variable to missing if it takes on one of three values in dplyr. Consider the following data frame `have`:

```
id  married hrs_workperwk
1   1       40
2   1       55
3   1       70
4   0       -1
5   1       99
6   0       -2
7   0       10
8   0       40
9   1       45
```

-1, -2, and 99 are illegal values. The new data frame `want` should look like this:

```
id  married hrs_workperwk
1   1       40
2   1       55
3   1       70
4   0       NA
5   1       NA
6   0       NA
7   0       10
8   0       40
9   1       45
```

I could use base R to solve this quickly, but dplyr is often convenient to work in when I'm already using `mutate()`. Alas, that means I currently use multiple nested `if_else()` functions:

```
want <- mutate(have, 
hrs_workperwk = if_else(hrs_workperwk < 0, as.numeric(NA), 
                if_else(hrs_workperwk = 99, as.numeric(NA), hrs_workperwk)))
```

Is there a way to do this with only one if_else() function? Ideally something like this:

```
want <- mutate(have, 
hrs_workperwk = if_else(hrs_workperwk = c(-2, -1, 99), as.numeric(NA), hrs_workperwk))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%in%`:

```
want <- have %>% 
  mutate(hrs_workperwk = ifelse(hrs_workperwk %in% c(-1, -2, 99), NA, hrs_workperwk))
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `replace`

```
df %>%
  mutate(hrs_workperwk = replace(hrs_workperwk, hrs_workperwk %in% c(-1, -2, 99), NA))
#  id married hrs_workperwk
#1  1       1            40
#2  2       1            55
#3  3       1            70
#4  4       0            NA
#5  5       1            NA
#6  6       0            NA
#7  7       0            10
#8  8       0            40
#9  9       1            45
```

---

Or another option is `case_when`

```
df %>%
   mutate(hrs_workperwk = case_when(hrs_workperwk %in% c(-1, -2, 99)~ NA_integer_,
                      TRUE ~ hrs_workperwk))
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
df1$hrs_workperwk[df1$hrs_workperwk %in% c(-1,-2,99)] <- NA
```

or

```
is.na(df1$hrs_workperwk) <- df1$hrs_workperwk %in% c(-1,-2,99)
```

output for both cases:

```
#   id married hrs_workperwk
# 1  1       1            40
# 2  2       1            55
# 3  3       1            70
# 4  4       0            NA
# 5  5       1            NA
# 6  6       0            NA
# 7  7       0            10
# 8  8       0            40
# 9  9       1            45
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
id  married hrs_workperwk
1   1       40
2   1       55
3   1       70
4   0       -1
5   1       99
6   0       -2
7   0       10
8   0       40
9   1       45",h=T,strin=F)
```

Comment: I totally forgot `is.na<-` is a function. Neat.

Comment: It's a confusing one in my opinion, one might think its purpose is to replace `NAs` and not assign `NA` values, I wouldn't use it in my code, but for completeness :).